# Openbox desktop menu text bug

Tags: arch-linux, context-menu, openbox

I have the newest Arch with Open Box on my WMware Workstation. Since the installation I had deformation of text in the 'right click' menu. The fields work and as you can see, I did some customization of the fields, but the text bug still remains.

Menu deformation picture:

[image: Menu deformation picture]

Comment: Did you install VMware Tools in the archlinux guest?  VMware, VM menu, install or reinstall VMware Tools. If it is available to use, you should try it.

Comment: Installing VM utils is a good idea, but it shouldn't be necessary for this to work correctly. It looks like the font is being rendered too large.

Comment: Yes, I did install the VMware Tools and even tried reinstalling them. Nothing helped. Other VM features such as shared folders are working properly.